# minimalistic Java web interface like Pythons WSGI

Tags: java, python, asp.net-mvc, servlets, wsgi

Python has a minimalistic and elegant web interface called [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/). The simplest possible application looks like this:

```
def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return ['Hello world!\n']
```

`environ` is something like a request object and `start_response` is a function to set the resonse headers. The response body is an iterable object, here a list with a single String ('Hello world!\n'). This simple interface unifies what is done in Java with Servlets and Filters.

I wonder if something similar could be written in Java. To return an iterator in Java would be slower than using a stream, I would expect. So I think that passing in an OutputStream (wrapped in a response object), like the Servlet API does, is the best solution. It would look like this:

```
public interface Handler {
    void handle(Request req, Response res);
}
```

However, I'd prefer if the response would be returned:

```
public interface Handler {
    Response handle(Request req);
}
```

But then the only way to pass in an OutputStream would be the Request (Request#createResponse()).

[ASP.NET actions return "Result"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-controller-overview-cs) objects, but I don't know much about it and have no idea how streaming is performed by the framework. How would you do something similar in Java?

I'm looking forward to your ideas for a simple and elegant Java web API.

Answer (score 0):

Using native IO and Network API of java, we can create ServerSocket of java.net package.

Comment: A raw socket is a *bit* too low level ;-)